# How can I prevent Jboss from translating xml entities into html entities?

Tags: html, webkit, seam, jboss5.x, html-entities

older Webkit versions have a problem with html-entities such as nbsp and ouml etc. As a solution I was advised [here](http://techtrouts.com/webkit-entity-nbsp-not-defined-convert-html-entities-to-xml/) to change my html-entities to xml-entities. The problem should then be solved, but it isn't, and I think that might be due to JBoss. It seems that when the page is rendered it translates xml entities like #160 to nbsp which doesn't work in older webkit browsers (and a few current android browsers). Does anyone know how to prevent JBoss from doing that? I even tried using normal symbols such as "ö" instead of ouml or #246 but to no avail.

I tried finding out if anyone else has this problem with JBoss but I couldn't find anything.
I'd appreciate any help I can get :)

-Dularion